# SELECT statement subquery

Tags: mysql, select

EDIT:  I need the overall total in there subtracting both direct and indirect minutes.

I'm trying to SUM M. Minutes as an alias "dminutes".  Then, take the SUM of M.minutes again and subtract M.minutes that have "indirect" column value (and give it "inminutes" alias). However, it's showing me null, so the syntax is wrong. Suggestions?

```
table = tasks
column = task_type


Example:
M.minutes total = 60 minutes
M. minutes (with "direct" task_type column value) = 50 minutes (AS dminutes)
M. minutes (with "indirect" task_type column value) = 10 minutes (AS inminutes)
```

SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
U.user_name,
SUM(M.minutes) as dminutes,
ROUND(SUM(M.minutes))-(SELECT (SUM(M.minutes)) from summary s WHERE ta.task_type='indirect') as inminutes
FROM summary S
JOIN users U ON U.user_id = S.user_id
JOIN tasks TA ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
JOIN minutes M ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
WHERE DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
AND TIME(submit_date) BETWEEN '00:00:01' and '23:59:59'
GROUP BY U.user_name 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work.

You might have to tweak it a little.

```
SELECT direct.duser_id, indirect.iminutes, direct.dminutes, 
    direct.dminutes - indirect.iminutes FROM
    (SELECT U.user_id AS iuser_id, SUM(M.minutes) AS iminutes
    FROM summary S
    JOIN users U 
    ON U.user_id = S.user_id
    JOIN minutes M 
    ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
    JOIN tasks TA 
    ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
    WHERE TA.task_type='indirect'
    AND DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
    AND TIME(submit_date) BETWEEN '00:00:01' and '23:59:59'
    GROUP BY U.user_id) AS indirect
JOIN
    (SELECT U.user_id AS duser_id, SUM(M.minutes) AS dminutes
    FROM summary S
    JOIN users U 
    ON U.user_id = S.user_id
    JOIN minutes M 
    ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
    JOIN tasks TA 
    ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
    WHERE TA.task_type='direct'
    AND DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
    AND TIME(submit_date) BETWEEN '00:00:01' and '23:59:59'
    GROUP BY U.user_id) AS direct
WHERE indirect.iuser_id = direct.duser_id
```

Comment: I think you are right and on the right track!  Although, I'm getting a syntax error.. I've tried tweaking it, but it's not liking the temp table join "ON iuser_id = duser_id".  Error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON iuser_id = duser_id)'

Comment: You, my friend, are some kind of sorcerer! haha  It worked perfectly, thank you!!

Comment: It's crazy to me how much coding is required to make simple subtraction work in Mysql.  Don't get me wrong, I love it because I only have to do it once and then the statement is there forever to use, but man... lol

Comment: Haha, glad it worked for you! And yeah, some things are a bit difficult to do with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

`SUM` is a nasty little function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

> Returns the sum of expr. If the return set has no rows, SUM() returns
>   NULL. The DISTINCT keyword can be used to sum only the distinct values
>   of expr.
>
> SUM() returns NULL if there were no matching rows.

Try wrapping SUM to a COALESCE or an IFNULL:

```
... COALESCE( SUM(whatever), 0) ...
```

Comment: That was a copy-paste malfunction :)